# ckeditor - mediaEmbed with upload image

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ckeditor

I have CKEDITOR with option to upload image, and now i want to add mediaembed for adding youtube videos to the editor.

i've add the line: `config.extraPlugins = 'MediaEmbed';` but nothing happen, the new button of mediaembed is not there.

I have the next config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{

config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "ckeditor/ImageBrowser.aspx";
config.filebrowserImageWindowWidth = 780;
config.filebrowserImageWindowHeight = 720;
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "ckeditor/LinkBrowser.aspx";
config.filebrowserWindowWidth = 500;
config.filebrowserWindowHeight = 650;
config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;
config.extraPlugins = 'MediaEmbed';

};
```

The mediaembed folder is in ~/ckedtior/plugins/

Where i'm wrong? the button of mediaembed is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add 'MediaEmbed' to ckeditor.js in the line with 'Flash','Table' ....